# Getting the last inserted record id of a database table in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a database table A which stores records, A has a primary key (recordid)  with auto_increment, each time i insert a record in to A, i get  the inserted recordid and store it in another masterTable.

I am using a select statement as soon i do an insert into A to get the recordid like this:

select recordid from A  order by recordid DESC LIMIT 1;

But i ran into a problem today, where in two records were inserted(by different threads) at the same time and i ended up storing wrong recordid in the master id( the same recordid for both the txns)

I heard about Statement.getGeneratedKeys(), I would like to know if that really helps resolve the issue. Or what is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [getGeneratedKeys](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method. This [forum post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/307373/JDBC/java/Get-last-ID-INSERT-statement) will help.

May I also recommend that you use an ORM tool like [Hibernate](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2004/jw-1018-hibernate.html). In Hibernate you would do something like this:

```
myTable = new myTable();
myTable.prop1 = prop1;
myTable.prop2 = prop2;
int id = session.save(myTable);
```

Hibernate will issue the appropriate SQL commands (depending on the database selected) and return you the auto-generated id.

Comment: If MySQL JDBC driver implements it.

Comment: That's true. If the JDBC driver doesn't support it, you need to rely on database specific methods to get the ID.

Comment: @kgiannakakis - `session.save(myTable)` doesn't return an `int`. It however, returns `java.io.serializable` and the `getGeneratedKeys()` method is not supported by any implementation of the JDBC drivers until now. So neither of the  two cases which you mentioned would be successful as obvious. Do they really work?

Comment: @Lion - `Integer` does implement `Serializable`. So using boxing you can get an int out of `session.save(myTable)`, provided of course that the mapping of your table is such as to return an int. This method works. I have successfully tested getGeneratedKeys method with MySQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL JDBC driver does support the `getGeneratedKey()` method. Have a look at the section [20.3.5.1.4. Retrieving AUTO_INCREMENT Column Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id) of the MySQL manual where:

> we demonstrates the use of the new JDBC-3.0 method `getGeneratedKeys()` which is now the preferred method to use if you need to retrieve AUTO_INCREMENT keys.

Answer (score 1):

In databases that don't support generatedKeys you may be able to get the ID into a return parameter. Oracle for example provides the RETURNING xxx INTO ? syntax where xxx is your column name.