# Using Auto Increment with MySQL and need to retrieve that number

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a database in which I need some IDs to be autoincremented, but I also need that ID that gets auto incremented to be the Foreign Key for another table. Is there a way to recover that number within the same transaction to insert values into the second table?

As in:
1) Create a user
2) Retrieve the ID number generated by the auto increment ( for example: AI:5 )
3) Insert values into a table called Doctor, that needs that number retrieved by that user, all within same transaction...

I know that JSP has some function to recover that ID generated but not sure about MySQL.
Another thing is, I can't just send a query to recover the last generated ID because for example if 10 accounts got created at the same time I might not get the supposed number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select last insert id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266604/select-last-insert-id)

Comment: Another comparable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567908/getting-last-insert-id-for-mysql-after-update

Comment: Many other similar questions to be found.  The last insert id is dependent on the active connection, so if you attempt to retrieve it with a page connection while several others have meanwhile been inserted, you still get the correct id.

Comment: @Michael, no, the question on top, is about PHP and here it mention JSP.

Comment: @stivlo `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is an API independent MySQL function.

Comment: I edited my comment, I was referring to the first question, it's only about PHP.

Comment: @Michael, someone might suggest a Java solution, maybe you should find a duplicate that is about Java.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699761/getting-the-last-inserted-record-id-of-a-database-table-in-java

Comment: @Michael I agree with you for this last one.

Comment: @Michael, Nevermind my question, u answered it in the 3rd reply thanks

Answer (score 3):

For a pure MySQL solution:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

For a Java way:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```